# What is the fastest way to view GB's of images across the network?

Tags: images, open-source, viewer

I have about 200 GB's of photos shared on another pc running linux. What is the fastest way to view these images? I'm looking to look through them quickly and maybe export them to a specified size.

I've tried shotwell on Ubuntu and it just seems to move slower than I work.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Opera 11 and using the Unite feature to stream the photos. More [here](http://unite.opera.com/overview/).